# Linear response theory of spin Seebeck effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, field-theory, spin-statistics

I am trying to re-derive the expressions of linear response theory given in the following article:

> *[Theory of the Spin Seebeck Effect](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6407)*,
>
> Hiroto Adachi, Ken-ichi Uchida, Eiji Saitoh, Sadamichi Maekawa

The behavior of a time-dependent quantity (itinerant spin density) is described by Bloch equation (equ.12 of Main text)
$$\partial_t \vec{s} = -\frac{1}{\tau}\bigg(\vec{s}-\chi J_{sd}[\hat{z} + \vec{m}]\bigg)-\frac{J_{sd}}{\hbar}[\hat{z} + \vec{m}]\times \vec{s} + \vec{l}$$

$J_{sd}$ is interaction. $\tau$ is spin-flip relaxation. $\chi$ is susceptibility. The field $\vec{l}$ is Gaussian ensemble
$$\langle l^\mu(t)\rangle = 0 ; \qquad \langle  l^\mu(t) l^\nu(t')\rangle = \frac{2k_BT_N\chi}{\tau}\delta_{\mu,\nu}\delta(t-t')$$
Then next they define spin current $I_s$ as
$$I_s = \langle\partial_ts^z(t)\rangle$$
My question is how to calculate $I_s$ here? They say that they use perturbative approach on $J_{sd}$ and get the following result
$$I_s = \langle\partial_ts^z(t)\rangle = \frac{J}{\hbar} \mathcal{Im}\langle s^+(t)m^-(t')\rangle_{t\to t'}$$
where $s^\pm = s^x\pm is^y$ and same for $m^\pm = m^x\pm im^y$.

I started with extracting the z-component of equ.12 i.e.
$$\partial_t s^z = \bigg[-\frac{s^z}{\tau} + l^z\bigg]+ J_{sd}\bigg[\frac{\chi}{\tau}+\frac{\chi m^z}{\tau} +\frac{s^-m^+ - s^+m^-}{2i\hbar}\bigg]$$
How can I apply the perturbation approach on this equation and calculate $\langle\partial_ts^z(t)\rangle$?

Note: May be I am asking a very childish thing. If so, please suggest me any readings to understand this kind of mathematics.